# Can I use it this way? I see no reason why I can not

Tags: grammar

Friend of friend: She's Happy

Me: Is it because of her meeting me/having met me?

Can I say it that way
rather than
is this because she has met me?

Answer (score 1):

For sure.

In most situations, I would use your top examples ('her meeting me' and 'having met me') long before I would use 'because she has met me'.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what meaning you want to convey. Your three examples do not mean exactly the same thing. (BTW '...because of her meeting me...' is a bit awkward, probably because the 'her' is redundant).

If you say 'She is happy because she has met me' that will be understood as referring to a single meeting. Either you are someone really famous whom she had been hoping to meet or you have such an amazing personality that a single meeting makes her happy.

'...because of having met me' carries similar connotations.

Not being famous or having an amazing personality, I would nevertheless like to think that my wife of many years is happy 'because of meeting me' (and, by implication all the wonderful things that followed from that meeting).